# amazon fetch product of different categories Vacuum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I and writing back end for a mobile app. I have to show women bags and shoes on front page in Json. I am using vacuum and I have configured it properly.
But I don't know how to fetch products from two different categories.

```
response = requestd.item_search(query: {'SearchIndex' => 'FashionWomen','Keywords' => 'shoes','ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images"})
```

Can anybody please explain? Later on I also want to fetch products with multiple asin number. Single item can be fetched but how to fetch multiple items?

```
 request.item_lookup(query: {'ItemId' => '0679753354'})
```